# hasOwnProperty() not working in Chrome for array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, hash

I've inherited some Javascript code and I'm not really a Javascript expert.

We have an object that acts like a collection of hashes and values called `buckets`. It has properties that are the hash value and each property is an object. Here's what it looks like in the browser's debugger:

[image]

We have a `containsKey()` function that uses `hasOwnProperty()` to check for the existence of a hash in the buckets object.

```
containsKey: function(key) {
    var hash = this.comparer.getObjectHashCode(key);
    if (!this.buckets.hasOwnProperty(hash))
        return false;

    var array = this.buckets[hash];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (this.comparer.areEqual(array[i].key, key))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code has worked flawlessly for at least 3 years. In the past week or two it stopped working in Chrome. Still works fine in IE (not sure about FF).

It seems to me that it ought to continue to work. I've validated that `buckets` contains the hash property being searched. But the `hasOwnProperty()` is now returning false.

Is there a more appropriate function I should use here?

Here's where it's failing in the debugger:

[image]

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are there errors reported in the console? How do you know that the problem is with how `.hasOwnProperty()` works?

Comment: please add the code, here or jsfiddle...

Comment: As I wrote in the question: "I've validated that buckets contains the hash property being searched. But the `hasOwnProperty()` is now returning false." That's how I know the problem is with `hasOwnProperty()`. 
What code should I add? This is the relevant function. The entire code base is 53K lines.

Comment: Is it possible that the state of the `buckets` object changes between the point in time that you perform that validation in the debugger and the point in time that the code in question actually runs? Have you added some `console.log()` calls in the function to dump out the state of affairs directly at the point when it matters?

Comment: Something tells me that changes were made that would alter the value of `this`. Can't tell though without a complete example. It takes time to reduce 53k lines of code to a minimal example, but that's simply what's needed if basic debugging hasn't shown you the problem.

Comment: Please see the second screenshot I added.

Comment: A quick test shows that `.hasOwnProperty()` works. `var o={};
o[-1525029354] = "foo";
o.hasOwnProperty(-1525029354); // true` Were there recent changes made to your app? Do you version the software?

Comment: The app has changed, but this particular library (which is isolated in its own .js file) has not changed in 3 years. I've tried to set up a fiddle for it and I can't get jsFiddle to work. It keeps giving me javascript errors that make no sense. I'm now wondering if you Chrome install is somehow messed up. It would have to be a company-wide issue, though because the problem appears to be affecting everyone.

Comment: [Can't reproduce on Chrome 54](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNPZom?editors=0011). Maybe the `hasOwnProperty` function was overridden somewhere and is not working as it's supposed to.

Comment: There's clearly something wrong. I don't know what it is, but I doubt it's something I'm going to find a fix for here.
What I've discovered is that `propertyIsEnumerable()` works correctly (returns true for the same values), but `hasOwnProperty()` does not. I've tried tracing into `hasOwnProperty()`, but I cannot, so I don't think it's being overridden. 
I think something is corrupting the javascript or data or something. I don't know, but it's also clear that in simple tests, `hasOwnProperty()` functions correctly (as per the example squint added above).

Comment: @gre_gor Your code doesn't work in Chrome 55.0.2883.87 Thank you!!! I should be able to use it for a bug submission.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appears to be some sort of bug in Chrome that was introduced when we upgraded from Chrome version 54.0.2840.99 to 55.0.2883.75 on Dec. 2, 2016.

The solution to our particular issue was to change our hash function to only return positive numbers. While small tests using negative numbers appears to work fine (as per squint's example in the comments), in our application they no longer work in Chrome.

I don't have a lot of time to dig into it. I don't know if it has to do with the number of items (we only have about 170 or so items in our "bucket").

**Update:**

gre_gor, in a comment above produced a sample that demonstrates the bug:

```
obj = {
  buckets: {},
  comparer: {
    getObjectHashCode: function(str) { // hardcoded magic hashing
      return {
        "SUPPLYINVENTORY/SUPTRANSENTRY": -1525029354,
        "PROPANE/LOADPROPANETOGROWERAR": 115289505
      }[str.toUpperCase()];
    },
    areEqual: function(a, b) {
      return a.toUpperCase() == b.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  containsKey: function(key) {
    var hash = this.comparer.getObjectHashCode(key);
    if (!this.buckets.hasOwnProperty(hash))
      return false;

    var array = this.buckets[hash];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (this.comparer.areEqual(array[i].key, key))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
};
obj.buckets[-1525029354] = [{
  key: "SUPPLYINVENTORY/SUPTRANSENTRY",
  value: "$SupTransEntry object"
}];
obj.buckets[115289505] = [{
  key: "PROPANE/LOADPROPANETOGROWERAR",
  value: "$LoadPropaneToGrowerAR object"
}];
console.log(obj.containsKey("SUPPLYINVENTORY/SUPTRANSENTRY"), obj.containsKey("PROPANE/LOADPROPANETOGROWERAR"));
```

The text "true true" should go to the console, but in Chrome 55, it produces "false true".

Thank you gre_gor for a test that reliably reproduces the issue. I've reported the bug to Google.

**Update #2:** A bug was submitted 3 days before my submission for it. The issue has been fixed and will be out soon enough that I'm not going to have to work around it. -- [Chromium Bug #673008](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=673008)

Comment: I worked around this by changing hasOwnProperty(hash) to hasOwnProperty(hash.toString()) in mscorlib.js for now. It is seen in a few places.